# Update svg style after php bdd request

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I am trying to do an dynamic map of a building, when a user enter the name of the person and the bdd will give me back his desk number, which is an ID in my svg paths but odk what i am doing wrong,
I am also trying to trigger a js method each time a user press a desk on the map it'll return all information about the person using the desk.

here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <form action = "validate.php" method = "post">
       <input type = "search" name = "nom">
       <button type= "submit" id='valider'>Recherche</button>
      </form>
    <div class="map" id="map">
        <div class="map__image">
            <svg version="1.0" class="tempo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="1528.000000pt" height="502.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1528.000000 
            502.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

    <g transform="translate(0.000000,502.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
    fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M130 2710 l0 -2220 5935 0 5935 0 1477 1001 c813 551 1532 1039 1599 1084 l120 81 -990 344 c-1258 436 -1538 533 -3231 1122 l-1390 483 -240 5 -240 5 -390 158 -389 157 -4098 0 -4098 0 0 -2220z m8575 2050 l370 -149 -725 -1 c-399 0 -2090 5 -3758 11 -1668 6 -3034 10 -3036 8 -3 -3 -13 -575 -16 -851 l0 -48 -700 0 -699 0 -1 590 0 590 4097 0 4098 -1 370 -149z m-6729 -150 l123 0 3 -52 3 -53 38 -3 37 -3 0 -290 c0 -186 4 -289 10 -289 6 0 10 107 10 300 l0 300 -40 0 c-34 0 -41 4 -46 24 -3 14 -4 33 -2 43 3 17 21 18 286 21 l282 2 0 -450 0 -450 158 2 157 2 -147 3 -148 4 0 444 0 445 265 0 265 0 0 -535 0 -535 135 0 c83 0 135 4 135 10 0 6 -48 10 -125 10 l-125 0 0 525 0 525 245 0 245 0 0 -520 0 -520 283 2 282 3 -277 2 -277 3 0 503 c-1 276 3 508 7 515 7 9 86 12 363 10 l354 -3 5 -530 c3 -291 7 -528 10 -525 2 3 6 241 9 530 l6 525 63 0 c34 -1 627 -2 1317 -3 l1255 -2 0 -530 0 -530 170 0 c107 0 170 4 170 10 0 6 -60 10 -160 10 l-160 0 0 320 0 320 160 0 160 0 0 85 0 85 -160 0 -160 0 0 115 0 115 93 0 c50 0 163 -3 250 -7 l157 -6 0 -519 c0 -339 3 -518 10 -518 7 0 10 180 10 520 l0 520 525 0 525 0 2 -522 2 -523 7 375 c3 206 7 441 8 523 l1 147 404 0 c342 0 405 -2 409 -14 8 -19 8 -983 0 -1002 -4 -12 -55 -14 -324 -14 -206 0 -319 -4 -319 -10 0 -6 117 -10 330 -10 l330 0 0 520 c0 304 4 520 9 520 11 0 4327 -1496 4341 -1505 6 -4 9 -229 9 -628 l0 -622 -22 -16 c-12 -8 -265 -180 -562 -381 -297 -201 -723 -489 -948 -641 l-407 -277 -565 0 -565 0 0 640 0 640 -165 0 c-103 0 -165 -4 -165 -10 0 -6 58 -10 155 -10 l155 0 0 -420 0 -420 -155 0 -155 0 0 -82 0 -83 155 3 155 3 0 -131 0 -130 -255 0 -255 0 0 642 c0 353 -2 639 -5 636 -3 -3 -7 -291 -8 -639 l-2 -634 -1850 0 -1850 0 -2 270 c-2 149 -3 404 -3 568 l0 297 -167 -2 -168 -2 163 -3 162 -3 0 -350 0 -350 -160 0 -160 0 0 -90 0 -90 160 0 160 0 0 -125 0 -125 -255 0 -255 0 0 640 c0 420 -3 640 -10 640 -7 0 -10 -220 -10 -640 l0 -640 -260 0 -260 0 0 120 0 120 180 0 180 0 0 90 0 90 -180 0 -180 0 0 425 0 425 165 0 c103 0 165 4 165 10 0 6 -63 10 -170 10 l-170 0 0 -645 0 -645 -1050 0 -1050 0 0 645 0 645 -170 0 c-107 0 -170 -4 -170 -10 0 -6 62 -10 165 -10 l165 0 0 -425 0 -425 -170 0 -170 0 0 -85 0 -85 170 0 170 0 0 -125 0 -125 -265 0 -265 0 2 645 3 645 -177 0 c-112 0 -178 -4 -178 -10 0 -6 64 -10 172 -10 l171 0 -6 -292 c-4 -161 -7 -353 -7 -425 l0 -133 -160 0 -160 0 0 -85 0 -85 160 0 160 0 0 -125 0 -125 -250 0 -250 0 0 645 0 645 -165 0 c-103 0 -165 -4 -165 -10 0 -6 58 -10 155 -10 l155 0 0 -635 0 -635 -255 0 -255 0 0 645 0 645 -145 0 c-90 0 -145 -4 -145 -10 0 -6 52 -10 135 -10 l135 0 0 -635 0 -635 -517 2 -518 3 -3 545 c-1 300 0 555 3 568 l5 22 297 0 c163 0 294 2 291 5 -3 3 -284 5 -626 5 l-622 0 -5 23 c-3 12 -4 123 -3 247 l3 225 128 3 127 3 0 257 c0 141 3 490 7 775 l6 517 370 0 369 0 -7 -773 -8 -774 609 -6 c335 -4 700 -7 812 -7 l202 0 0 535 0 535 -185 0 -185 0 0 248 0 249 -277 6 c-153 4 -340 7 -415 7 l-138 0 0 439 c0 342 3 441 13 445 6 3 72 4 146 1 74 -3 189 -5 257 -5z m5463 -256 l31 -6 0 -69 0 -69 -155 0 -155 0 0 75 0 75 124 0 c68 0 138 -3 155 -6z m-7111 -644 l62 0 0 -765 0 -766 -122 3 -123 3 -3 759 c-2 601 0 762 10 768 7 5 36 7 63 4 28 -3 78 -6 113 -6z m2042 -770 l0 -770 -605 0 -605 0 0 770 0 770 605 0 605 0 0 -770z m375 218 c-1 -21 -2 -252 -3 -513 l-2 -475 -182 0 -181 0 6 353 c4 193 7 425 7 515 l0 162 178 -2 177 -3 0 -37z m11828 -303 c317 -110 577 -202 577 -205 0 -6 -1186 -810 -1194 -810 -3 0 -6 276 -6 614 l0 614 23 -6 c13 -4 283 -97 600 -207z m-13783 -1775 l0 -570 -322 2 -323 3 -3 545 c-1 300 0 555 3 568 l5 22 320 0 320 0 0 -570z m5820 -230 l0 -80 -155 0 -155 0 0 80 0 80 155 0 155 0 0 -80z m-3170 -5 l0 -75 -165 0 -165 0 0 75 0 75 165 0 165 0 0 -75z m2468 -2 l3 -73 -176 0 -175 0 0 68 c0 38 3 72 7 76 4 3 81 5 172 4 l166 -3 3 -72z m-3018 -3 l0 -70 -155 0 -155 0 0 70 0 70 155 0 155 0 0 -70z m7960 5 l0 -65 -150 0 -150 0 0 65 0 65 150 0 150 0 0 -65z"/>
    <path d="M11310 2561 c0 -5 84 -38 188 -73 l187 -65 3 -137 3 -136 -166 0 c-105 0 -165 -4 -165 -10 0 -7 111 -9 328 -8 l327 3 3 95 3 95 -108 37 c-59 19 -219 74 -355 121 -137 48 -248 82 -248 78z m558 -201 l132 -45 0 -81 c0 -57 -4 -83 -12 -86 -7 -2 -73 -2 -145 0 l-133 4 0 130 c0 101 3 129 13 126 7 -2 72 -23 145 -48z"/> 
    <path d="M9400 2990 c0 -6 72 -10 195 -10 l195 0 0 -425 0 -425 -400 0 -400 0 0 390 0 390 85 0 c50 0 85 4 85 10 0 6 -36 10 -88 10 l-89 0 -6 -212 c-4 -116 -7 -298 -7 -405 l0 -193 273 0 c151 0 403 -3 560 -7 215 -5 287 -3 287 5 0 9 -42 12 -145 12 l-146 0 1 215 1 215 260 0 c200 0 259 -3 260 -12 1 -7 1 -109 -1 -225 l-2 -213 441 0 c287 0 441 3 441 10 0 7 -150 10 -430 10 l-430 0 0 370 c0 217 4 370 9 370 5 0 177 -58 382 -130 324 -112 398 -135 378 -116 -10 9 -770 268 -774 264 -3 -3 -6 -74 -8 -159 l-2 -154 -255 3 c-140 1 -258 6 -262 10 -4 4 -4 94 -1 200 l6 192 159 0 c99 0 158 4 158 10 0 6 -128 10 -365 10 -237 0 -365 -4 -365 -10z"/> 
    <path d="M7077 3270 c-93 -16 -171 -31 -175 -34 -10 -11 32 -6 186 19 84 14 159 25 167 25 13 0 15 -27 15 -175 l0 -175 -180 0 -180 0 0 50 0 50 -97 -2 -98 -2 88 -3 87 -4 0 -44 0 -45 -375 0 -375 0 0 -380 0 -380 380 0 380 0 0 -55 0 -54 -87 -4 -88 -3 98 -2 97 -2 0 60 0 60 185 0 185 0 0 -180 0 -180 -22 5 c-38 9 -336 55 -354 55 -49 0 14 -14 197 -45 l203 -34 194 29 c107 16 197 31 200 34 10 10 -40 6 -178 -15 -74 -11 -156 -22 -183 -26 l-47 -6 2 179 3 179 163 3 162 2 0 -65 0 -65 100 0 c60 0 100 4 100 10 0 6 -37 10 -90 10 l-90 0 0 55 0 55 360 -2 360 -3 0 383 0 382 -355 0 -355 0 0 40 0 40 93 2 92 2 -100 5 -100 6 -3 -47 -3 -48 -175 0 -174 0 0 175 c0 160 1 175 18 175 9 0 82 -11 162 -25 80 -14 154 -25 165 -24 l20 0 -20 9 c-26 12 -325 60 -362 59 -15 0 -104 -13 -196 -29z m622 -725 l0 -365 -769 0 -770 0 0 365 0 365 770 0 769 0 0 -365z m651 0 l0 -365 -320 0 -320 0 0 365 0 365 320 0 320 0 0 -365z"/> 
    <path d="M3100 2680 l0 -530 883 0 882 0 0 530 0 530 -882 0 -883 0 0 -530z m1750 0 l0 -510 -865 0 -865 0 0 510 0 510 865 0 865 0 0 -510z"/>


    <path id="1" d="M6550 4223 l0 -322 88 -3 c48 -2 122 -2 165 0 l77 3 0 322 0 322 -165 0 -165 0 0 -322z m170 157 l0 -150 -80 0 -80 0 0 150 0 150 80 0 80 0 0 -150z m149 13 c0 -75 -3 -143 -6 -150 -4 -9 -26 -13 -69 -13 l-64 0 0 150 0 150 70 0 71 0 -2 -137z m-149 -328 l0 -155 -80 0 -80 0 0 155 0 155 80 0 80 0 0 -155z m148 50 c2 -55 1 -124 -3 -152 l-6 -53 -65 0 -64 0 0 155 0 156 68 -3 67 -3 3 -100z"/>
    <path id="2" d="M4830 4148 l0 -318 160 0 160 0 0 158 c1 275 -1 466 -5 470 -2 2 -74 4 -159 5 l-156 2 0 -317z m170 152 l0 -150 -75 0 -75 0 0 150 0 150 75 0 75 0 0 -150z m140 0 l0 -150 -65 0 -65 0 0 150 0 150 65 0 65 0 0 -150z m-140 -310 l0 -150 -75 0 -75 0 0 150 0 150 75 0 75 0 0 -150z m140 0 l0 -150 -65 0 -65 0 0 150 0 150 65 0 65 0 0 -150z"/> 
     <path id="3" d="M5770 4303 l0 -163 165 0 165 0 0 160 0 160 -87 1 c-49 1 -123 2 -165 3 l-78 1 0 -162z m170 2 l0 -145 -80 0 -80 0 0 145 0 145 80 0 80 0 0 -145z m150 0 l0 -145 -70 0 -70 0 0 145 0 145 70 0 70 0 0 -145z"/> 
     <path  id="4" d="M10079 4266 c-191 -531 -304 -862 -295 -864 13 -5 282 -101 304 -109 9 -4 13 -2 9 4 -9 14 72 255 90 269 8 7 10 14 5 15 -6 2 37 137 94 299 57 162 103 301 104 308 0 6 -6 12 -13 12 -8 0 -75 22 -150 49 l-137 48 -11 -31z m98 -11 l51 -18 -34 -101 c-20 -56 -42 -120 -51 -143 l-15 -41 -56 19 c-31 11 -60 23 -64 27 -5 5 9 57 31 118 58 162 60 166 74 162 6 -3 35 -13 64 -23z m141 -50 c28 -11 52 -24 52 -30 0 -9 -64 -206 -85 -262 -3 -9 -21 -7 -67 9 -35 11 -66 24 -70 27 -4 4 10 56 31 116 57 161 60 167 74 163 6 -3 36 -13 65 -23z m-198 -270 c0 -16 -90 -269 -99 -278 -6 -6 -110 25 -129 39 -2 1 20 67 49 147 l51 144 64 -20 c35 -12 64 -26 64 -32z m96 -25 l62 -22 -45 -126 c-25 -70 -48 -135 -50 -144 -3 -10 -10 -18 -17 -18 -11 0 -118 39 -124 45 -8 8 93 295 103 292 5 -3 38 -14 71 -27z m-258 -255 c28 -11 52 -24 52 -29 0 -27 -86 -256 -97 -256 -6 0 -36 10 -67 21 -49 19 -56 25 -50 43 35 114 89 246 98 243 6 -2 35 -12 64 -22z m207 -75 c3 0 -85 -260 -90 -268 -3 -4 -118 39 -128 47 -6 6 40 156 78 253 6 16 12 15 72 -7 36 -14 67 -25 68 -25z"/> 
    <path  id="5" d="M10776 4031 c-3 -5 -57 -159 -120 -342 -62 -184 -132 -385 -155 -448 -22 -63 -40 -115 -38 -116 17 -13 242 -83 249 -79 6 4 8 2 5 -3 -4 -6 4 -14 17 -17 13 -3 30 -8 38 -11 8 -3 14 1 14 12 0 26 196 587 206 591 4 2 6 7 3 12 -5 8 76 250 95 283 12 20 26 13 -168 81 -150 52 -139 49 -146 37z m44 -22 c-12 -8 -9 -10 12 -6 17 2 25 0 21 -6 -4 -6 2 -8 15 -5 12 4 20 2 16 -3 -3 -5 1 -9 8 -9 39 -1 39 -15 -6 -144 -24 -69 -46 -129 -49 -132 -10 -10 -148 40 -143 52 2 6 24 66 48 133 25 72 49 122 58 125 28 7 35 6 20 -5z m199 -65 l59 -17 -44 -130 c-24 -72 -48 -135 -52 -139 -8 -8 -99 18 -116 33 -8 7 23 105 75 247 10 26 5 26 78 6z m-259 -240 c40 -15 69 -32 67 -38 -2 -6 -21 -63 -42 -126 -21 -63 -41 -118 -44 -123 -9 -9 -146 37 -146 49 0 10 88 264 91 264 2 0 35 -12 74 -26z m152 -48 c9 0 14 -5 11 -10 -4 -5 3 -7 15 -4 12 4 20 2 17 -2 -3 -5 0 -10 7 -12 9 -3 -1 -43 -31 -134 -24 -71 -45 -130 -46 -131 0 -1 -30 7 -66 19 l-65 21 37 106 c59 170 56 163 82 155 12 -4 30 -8 39 -8z m-240 -235 l66 -22 -53 -152 c-53 -151 -53 -152 -83 -152 -17 -1 -29 2 -26 4 3 3 -16 13 -43 22 -26 9 -47 20 -47 25 7 43 101 304 109 301 5 -2 40 -14 77 -26z m156 -56 c31 -10 52 -22 49 -29 -2 -6 -26 -75 -53 -153 -35 -100 -54 -143 -67 -147 -9 -2 -15 0 -12 4 3 5 -19 16 -49 24 l-55 16 50 143 c27 78 52 148 54 156 3 7 11 11 18 8 6 -2 36 -12 65 -22z"/> 
    <path id="6" d="M11341 3398 c-74 -222 -140 -422 -147 -445 l-13 -42 149 -49 148 -50 147 437 c81 240 149 441 151 446 3 8 -277 107 -296 106 -3 -1 -66 -182 -139 -403z m279 337 c0 -14 -81 -258 -89 -267 -3 -4 -36 3 -72 14 l-66 22 43 130 c24 72 46 136 48 143 6 14 136 -25 136 -42z m137 -40 c2 -1 -19 -64 -45 -141 l-47 -139 -61 20 -62 20 50 142 50 142 57 -21 c31 -11 57 -22 58 -23z m-286 -230 l57 -18 -49 -145 c-27 -80 -50 -146 -52 -148 -3 -3 -126 34 -134 41 -2 1 73 234 92 284 3 7 11 11 18 8 6 -2 37 -12 68 -22z m189 -72 c0 -22 -95 -283 -103 -283 -21 0 -117 34 -117 41 0 6 51 155 95 276 3 9 20 7 64 -8 34 -12 61 -23 61 -26z m-304 -229 c27 -9 53 -20 58 -25 7 -6 -66 -240 -81 -258 -4 -6 -133 30 -133 37 0 24 87 262 95 262 6 0 34 -7 61 -16z m140 -50 c27 -9 52 -19 56 -23 7 -6 -71 -243 -83 -256 -7 -6 -99 22 -113 35 -9 9 71 260 83 260 4 0 30 -7 57 -16z"/> 
    <path id="7" d="M12170 3485 c-12 -36 -83 -240 -159 -454 -116 -329 -135 -391 -122 -397 35 -14 275 -94 276 -91 2 2 70 193 151 427 30 85 59 157 64 158 6 2 8 8 5 13 -3 5 17 74 46 154 28 80 50 148 48 150 -8 7 -212 75 -216 71 -2 -2 12 -9 31 -16 20 -6 36 -15 36 -20 0 -9 -91 -272 -97 -279 -5 -7 -115 34 -120 44 -2 6 18 71 45 145 43 119 52 135 71 133 30 -4 26 3 -8 15 l-30 11 -21 -64z m245 -26 c32 -12 55 -26 52 -32 -2 -7 -19 -52 -36 -102 -18 -49 -40 -109 -48 -133 -9 -24 -21 -41 -27 -39 -6 2 -34 12 -63 21 l-52 17 50 141 c27 77 49 142 49 144 0 8 20 4 75 -17z m-238 -255 c45 -16 52 -22 47 -39 -6 -19 -5 -19 8 -2 13 18 16 18 71 -3 31 -12 57 -25 57 -29 0 -9 -90 -264 -95 -269 -4 -5 -107 28 -117 37 -4 4 11 58 33 120 22 63 38 116 36 118 -2 2 -16 -31 -31 -74 -15 -43 -34 -97 -43 -120 l-15 -42 -47 18 c-25 10 -54 21 -63 24 -18 6 -8 40 77 276 3 7 11 11 18 8 6 -2 36 -13 64 -23z m-62 -316 c10 -10 -86 -278 -99 -278 -19 0 -111 34 -115 43 -2 5 18 70 44 146 l49 137 57 -21 c32 -11 61 -24 64 -27z m143 -43 c4 -3 -90 -269 -99 -279 -8 -9 -94 18 -113 35 -5 4 12 67 39 147 l49 139 60 -20 c34 -11 62 -21 64 -22z"/> 
    <path id="8" d="M12900 3303 c-10 -2 -31 -50 -57 -126 -47 -138 -196 -570 -241 -694 -16 -46 -25 -83 -20 -83 5 0 72 -25 149 -56 77 -31 142 -54 144 -52 7 7 315 886 315 899 0 4 -21 15 -47 25 -27 9 -84 32 -128 51 -97 42 -96 42 -115 36z m20 -14 c-12 -9 -11 -10 8 -6 12 3 20 2 17 -3 -2 -4 16 -13 40 -20 25 -7 45 -15 45 -19 0 -17 -93 -281 -99 -281 -4 0 -35 10 -70 21 -50 17 -61 25 -56 38 4 9 23 61 42 116 49 141 60 165 75 165 9 0 9 -3 -2 -11z m249 -105 c5 -5 -78 -254 -89 -267 -5 -5 -35 1 -68 13 l-61 22 50 141 c27 77 49 142 49 143 0 4 112 -45 119 -52z m-319 -214 c30 -12 61 -23 67 -25 9 -3 -1 -43 -33 -137 -26 -73 -49 -136 -53 -140 -7 -8 -109 26 -124 41 -4 4 14 69 40 144 27 75 48 137 48 137 0 0 25 -9 55 -20z m167 -57 c29 -9 53 -20 53 -24 0 -21 -93 -279 -101 -279 -8 0 -112 39 -117 45 -7 6 91 275 101 275 6 0 34 -8 64 -17z m-250 -244 l62 -20 -50 -142 c-27 -77 -51 -142 -52 -144 -2 -1 -33 9 -69 23 l-67 25 35 97 c58 164 65 182 73 182 4 0 35 -9 68 -21z m151 -54 c31 -10 52 -22 49 -29 -2 -6 -23 -68 -46 -138 -23 -69 -50 -132 -59 -140 -8 -7 -13 -8 -9 -2 4 7 -16 18 -54 29 -33 10 -58 21 -57 25 2 3 25 68 52 143 28 80 54 136 60 134 6 -2 35 -12 64 -22z"/> 
    <path id="52/53" d="M13608 2752 l-68 -3 -1 -47 c-1 -26 -3 -71 -5 -100 -3 -34 -1 -51 6 -47 6 4 10 -16 10 -55 0 -38 -4 -59 -10 -55 -5 3 -10 1 -10 -4 0 -7 56 -11 165 -11 l165 0 0 160 0 160 -62 1 c-35 1 -76 2 -93 3 -16 0 -60 0 -97 -2z m242 -87 l0 -75 -145 0 -145 0 0 75 0 75 145 0 145 0 0 -75z m0 -155 l0 -70 -145 0 -145 0 0 70 0 70 145 0 145 0 0 -70z"/> 
    <path id="9" d="M13155 2217 c-72 -48 -131 -91 -133 -96 -4 -12 340 -521 351 -521 6 0 213 137 265 176 3 2 -65 104 -313 469 l-40 60 -130 -88z m210 -46 c43 -65 79 -121 80 -126 0 -8 -114 -90 -118 -84 -8 10 -154 225 -160 236 -5 7 14 27 50 52 32 22 60 40 63 40 3 0 41 -53 85 -118z m-142 -74 c37 -56 75 -112 83 -124 15 -21 13 -23 -46 -63 -34 -23 -65 -38 -69 -34 -13 16 -161 234 -161 239 0 5 112 85 119 85 3 0 37 -46 74 -103z m326 -198 c39 -58 71 -111 71 -116 0 -15 -111 -86 -120 -76 -20 23 -160 233 -160 240 0 4 26 25 58 45 44 29 59 35 68 25 6 -7 43 -60 83 -118z m-139 -79 c44 -66 80 -123 80 -127 0 -4 -26 -25 -58 -45 -44 -29 -59 -35 -68 -25 -6 7 -45 62 -87 124 l-77 112 57 40 c32 22 61 40 65 40 4 1 44 -53 88 -119z"/> 
    <path id="10" d="M12574 1799 c-65 -44 -125 -86 -132 -93 -11 -10 18 -58 154 -257 91 -134 170 -248 174 -253 7 -7 269 162 269 174 0 3 -78 118 -173 257 l-173 252 -119 -80z m201 -56 l79 -116 -31 -26 c-17 -14 -45 -34 -61 -44 l-30 -17 -78 112 c-42 62 -77 118 -78 125 -1 13 91 81 110 82 6 1 46 -51 89 -116z m-135 -85 c41 -61 76 -114 78 -118 2 -4 -23 -26 -55 -49 -72 -51 -63 -54 12 -4 31 20 57 34 59 32 22 -27 156 -229 156 -235 -1 -10 -110 -88 -114 -82 -20 25 -327 481 -329 488 -2 10 91 79 108 79 6 0 44 -50 85 -111z m309 -170 l81 -117 -61 -42 c-36 -24 -65 -37 -70 -32 -24 24 -157 229 -152 236 8 12 107 77 115 75 4 -2 43 -56 87 -120z"/>
    <path id="11" d="M4410 1755 c0 -43 1 -45 30 -45 l30 0 0 -164 c0 -90 3 -171 6 -180 5 -14 28 -16 155 -16 l149 0 0 175 0 175 25 0 c23 0 25 3 25 50 l0 50 -210 0 -210 0 0 -45z m410 -3 l0 -38 -107 2 c-60 1 -150 2 -200 3 l-93 1 0 35 0 35 200 0 200 0 0 -38z m-200 -212 l0 -160 -65 0 -65 0 0 160 0 160 65 0 65 0 0 -160z m149 -5 l1 -165 -65 0 -65 0 0 165 0 165 64 0 65 0 0 -165z m-182 -172 c-20 -2 -52 -2 -70 0 -17 2 0 4 38 4 39 0 53 -2 32 -4z"/> 
    <path id="12" d="M3710 1740 c0 -49 1 -50 30 -50 l30 0 0 -160 0 -160 140 0 140 0 0 161 0 161 35 -4 35 -4 0 53 0 53 -205 0 -205 0 0 -50z m400 0 l0 -40 -195 0 -195 0 0 40 0 40 195 0 195 0 0 -40z m-210 -205 l0 -155 -60 0 -60 0 0 155 0 155 60 0 60 0 0 -155z m134 146 c3 -4 3 -74 -1 -155 l-6 -146 -54 0 -53 0 0 155 0 155 54 0 c30 0 57 -4 60 -9z"/> 
    <path id="13" d="M9720 1398 l0 -316 160 -1 160 -2 0 315 0 315 -160 3 -160 3 0 -317z m150 148 l0 -154 -65 0 -65 0 0 154 0 154 65 0 65 0 0 -154z m160 -1 l0 -155 -75 0 -75 0 0 155 0 155 75 0 75 0 0 -155z m-160 -305 l0 -140 -70 0 -70 0 0 140 0 140 70 0 70 0 0 -140z m160 0 l0 -140 -70 0 -70 0 0 140 0 140 70 0 70 0 0 -140z"/> 
    <path id="14" d="M9050 1550 l0 -159 160 -3 160 -3 0 163 0 162 -160 0 -160 0 0 -160z m310 0 l0 -150 -70 0 -70 0 0 150 0 150 70 0 70 0 0 -150z m-160 -5 l0 -145 -65 0 -65 0 -1 33 c0 17 -2 83 -5 145 l-4 112 70 0 70 0 0 -145z"/> <path id="34" d="M10560 1460 l0 -160 80 0 80 0 0 160 0 160 -80 0 -80 0 0 -160z m150 -5 l0 -145 -70 0 -70 0 0 145 0 145 70 0 70 0 0 -145z"/> 
    <path id="37/38" d="M11210 1355 l0 -165 160 0 160 0 0 165 0 165 -160 0 -160 0 0 -165z m150 0 l0 -155 -65 0 -65 0 0 155 0 155 65 0 65 0 0 -155z m160 0 l0 -155 -70 0 -70 0 0 155 0 155 70 0 70 0 0 -155z"/> 
    <path id="15" d="M12007 1427 c-75 -51 -137 -95 -137 -99 0 -7 332 -502 350 -521 10 -11 275 171 274 187 -1 11 -287 441 -334 503 l-17 22 -136 -92z m222 -48 c46 -66 79 -124 75 -128 -39 -33 -117 -80 -124 -76 -5 3 -44 58 -86 121 -42 63 -78 113 -80 111 -3 -2 32 -57 76 -122 44 -66 80 -121 80 -125 0 -3 -26 -22 -58 -42 -44 -29 -59 -35 -68 -25 -6 7 -45 62 -87 122 l-75 110 126 88 c70 48 129 87 132 87 3 0 43 -54 89 -121z m175 -257 c43 -64 78 -121 78 -126 1 -6 -26 -29 -60 -53 l-61 -44 -78 118 c-44 65 -82 123 -86 130 -7 12 96 92 118 92 6 0 45 -52 89 -117z m-135 -101 c45 -66 81 -122 81 -124 0 -6 -108 -77 -117 -77 -9 1 -161 222 -165 240 -3 15 100 92 113 85 4 -3 44 -59 88 -124z"/> 
    <path id="16" d="M7580 1374 c-1 -33 -2 -110 -3 -172 l-2 -112 168 0 167 0 0 168 0 167 -165 4 -165 3 0 -58z m150 -114 l0 -150 -65 0 -65 0 0 150 0 150 65 0 65 0 0 -150z m164 142 c3 -5 2 -74 -1 -155 l-6 -147 -69 0 -68 0 0 155 0 155 69 0 c39 0 72 -4 75 -8z"/> 
    <path id="17" d="M6930 1250 l0 -160 83 0 82 0 4 160 3 160 -86 0 -86 0 0 -160z m150 0 l0 -140 -65 0 -65 0 0 140 0 140 65 0 65 0 0 -140z"/> 
    <path id="18" d="M4930 920 l0 -320 165 0 165 0 0 320 0 320 -165 0 -165 0 0 -320z m160 155 l0 -145 -75 0 -75 0 0 138 c0 76 3 142 7 145 3 4 37 7 75 7 l68 0 0 -145z m160 0 l0 -145 -75 0 -75 0 0 145 0 145 75 0 75 0 0 -145z m-160 -310 l0 -155 -75 0 -75 0 0 155 0 155 75 0 75 0 0 -155z m160 0 l0 -155 -75 0 -75 0 0 155 0 155 75 0 75 0 0 -155z"/> 
    <path id="19" d="M3710 1180 c0 -49 1 -50 30 -50 l29 0 -6 -160 -6 -160 161 0 161 0 3 158 c3 156 3 157 26 156 20 -1 22 4 22 53 l0 53 -210 0 -210 0 0 -50z m410 0 l0 -40 -200 0 -200 0 0 40 0 40 200 0 200 0 0 -40z m-200 -210 l0 -150 -70 0 -70 0 0 150 0 150 70 0 70 0 0 -150z m150 0 l0 -150 -65 0 -65 0 0 150 0 150 65 0 65 0 0 -150z"/>
    <path id="20" d="M9080 913 l0 -303 170 0 170 0 0 300 0 299 -170 3 -170 3 0 -302z m320 152 l0 -135 -70 0 -70 0 0 135 0 135 70 0 70 0 0 -135z m-150 -5 l0 -130 -75 0 -75 0 0 130 0 130 75 0 75 0 0 -130z m150 -285 l0 -145 -70 0 -70 0 0 145 0 145 70 0 70 0 0 -145z m-152 -7 l-3 -143 -72 -3 -73 -3 0 146 0 145 75 0 76 0 -3 -142z"/> 
    <path id="21" d="M8430 975 l0 -165 160 0 160 0 0 165 0 165 -160 0 -160 0 0 -165z m140 0 l0 -155 -60 0 -60 0 0 155 0 155 60 0 60 0 0 -155z m170 -5 l0 -150 -80 0 -80 0 0 150 0 150 80 0 80 0 0 -150z"/> 
    <path id="22" d="M7580 840 c-1 -52 -2 -125 -3 -163 l-2 -67 163 0 162 0 0 160 0 160 -57 2 c-32 0 -104 2 -160 2 l-103 1 0 -95z m157 -67 l-2 -148 -67 -3 -68 -3 0 151 0 150 70 0 70 0 -3 -147z m153 -8 l0 -145 -65 0 -65 0 0 145 0 145 65 0 65 0 0 -145z"/> 
    <path id="23" d="M9760 776 l0 -166 165 0 165 0 0 163 0 162 -165 4 -165 3 0 -166z m150 -6 l0 -150 -65 0 -65 0 0 150 0 150 65 0 65 0 0 -150z m170 -5 l0 -145 -75 0 -75 0 0 145 0 145 75 0 75 0 0 -145z"/> 
    <path id="24" d="M6950 770 l0 -160 75 0 75 0 0 160 0 160 -75 0 -75 0 0 -160z m140 0 l0 -140 -60 0 -60 0 0 140 0 140 60 0 60 0 0 -140z"/> 
    <path id="25"  d="M11244 917 c-2 -7 -3 -80 -2 -162 l3 -150 163 -3 162 -2 0 165 0 165 -160 0 c-122 0 -162 -3 -166 -13z m152 -147  c-1 -77 -5 -143 -9 -146 -3 -4 -32 -7 -64 -7 l-58 0 -3 147 -3 146 70 0 70 0 -3 -140z  m161 -2 l-2 -143 -65 -6 c-36 -3 -68 -4 -72 -2 -5 2 -8 69 -8 149 l0 144 75 0 74 0 -2 -142z"/>
     </g>
     </svg>

    </div>

    </div>


       <script>
        <?php
        $('#valider').click(function(){
            document.getElementById('".$numero_bureau;"').style.color = "red";
        });
        ?>
        $('#map g').on("click", "path", function(){
                replay_click(this.id);
        });


        function replay_click(clicked_id){
            $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'find.php',                       
            type: "post",
            data: { getData: true },
            dataType: 'html',                     
            success: function(data, clicked_id)          
            {
            var infos = data;  
            infos.foreach(info)
            {
                $('#list_Output').html(info);
            }
       } 
        });
        }

</script>
    </body>
    </html>

 And i got 2 php  pages:

    <?php
    try
    {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=planinteractif;charset=utf8', 
    'root', 'root');
    if(isset($_POST['nom'])){
    $numero_bureau = $bdd->query('SELECT numero_bureau from User where nom=' + 
    $_POST['nom'] + ';')
    }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
       {
             die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
       }


       ?>


    <?php
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=planinteractif;charset=utf8', 
    'root', 'root');
        if(isset($_POST['nom'])){
        $infos = $bdd->query('SELECT * from User where numero_bureau=' + 
    $_POST['clicked_id'] + ';')
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }


    ?>
```

And a irrelevant css page i think, I am looking forward an answer i think its pretty easy but i am a beginner in web tech. TY

EDIT : taken note of advices you gave

Comment: Ids must not start with numbers. Try something like `b1`, `b2`, ... for your desk numbers.

Comment: Ok i've done it but it seems its not the pb here

Comment: You may want to read up on string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.string.php (specifically in your SQL queries.)

Comment: And where is `$numero_bureau` coming from on your first page?

Comment: '<?php echo $numero_bureau; ?>' in my js comes from my php

Comment: 'SELECT * from User where numero_bureau=' . '"$_POST['clicked_id']"' . ';'

is it better this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- your `<form>` has an `action`, but no `submit` control, so that action is never triggered.
- `onclick="Validate.php"` doesn't make sense. The attribute expects a Javascript command for client-side execution.
- Anyway, you are then defining another event listener function with `$document.getElementById('valider').click()` for the same event. THat mixes jQuery syntax with native syntax. Either you use jQUery and write

  ```
  $('#valider').click(function...);
  ```

  or you use the native API and write

  ```
  document.getElementById('valider').addEventListener(function...);
  ```
- The listener function contains *one static* `$numero_bureau` that is already mixed in server-side. Which number will that be?
- attributes to elements in the SVG namespace are case-sensitive. So the event listener attribute must be `onclick`, not `onClick`.
- the function called is `reply_click`, but the function defined has the name `replay_click`.
- the `this` in that function call is the global `window` object, not the element as you seem to think. Binding `this` to an element is a jQuery facility. For it to work, you need to define your event listener differently. Do not define a `onclick` attribute, but write this procedure as part of the script:

  ```
  $('#map g').on("click", "path", function () {
      replay_click(this.id);
  });
  ```

  This will add an event handler to the group enclosing the paths, but the `this` will be bound to the individual `<path>` element that was actually clicked.

Comment: Thaks for the tips, i'll implement them in the night.

Comment: First, editing the question in a way that the original problem can no longer be reproduced is something that is discouraged on Stackoverflow. On the other hand, I think you are strugling with some very basic concepts here (your new version has client-side Javascript commands in a place where PHP is executed server-side). It may be better suited if you present your code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a general code review.

Comment: I didn't know this i'll check it out. Ty for taking time to answer